# Best way to go about using multiple Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, module, onclick

So I'm intending to create a 'web arcade' in a sense, and I want different Javascript files to run when selecting a different game, what's the best way to go about doing this?

Is it possible to run a Javascript file on click of a certain button on the HTML page? I've tried using Modules but that seems a little complicated for my level at this moment, and was hoping for an easier alternative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to just include `script` tags with the `src` to your various files.  A think to note is that you must pay attention to the order that you are loading them in at.  Furthermore, you can just declare the variables regularly with `const/let/var` and use them regularly in files that load after it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="settings.js"></script>
    <script src="loop.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

```js
// settings.js
const worldData = {
  size: [230, 342]
};
```

```js
// loop.js
console.log(worldData); // logs `{ size: [230, 342] }` because this file is loaded after `settings.js`

function draw() { /* omit */ }
// call `draw` in a loop somewhere with HTML5 Canvas or P5
```

However, I would *strongly* suggest using ES Modules.  They make your code much more understandable like in the following project:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="loop.js" type="module"></script> <!-- Note that we only need this entry file -->
  </head>
</html>
```

```js
// settings.js
export const worldData = {
  size: [230, 342]
};
```

```js
// loop.js
import { worldData } from "./settings.js" // automatically sends request and gets script exports

console.log(worldData); // logs `{ size: [230, 342] }` because we already imported it

function draw() { /* omit */ }
// call `draw` in a loop somewhere with HTML5 Canvas or P5
```

The ES Modules version is much better because if you had many files that accessed the `worldData`, then you could just do an `import { worldData } from "/settings.js"` instead of having to ensure that your files are loaded in the proper order.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the brief yet detailed explanation! A few questions though, currently when I use `import {} from ./javascript.js'` it exports everything within the file, even when I specify only specific functions etc, is this supposed to happen?

Also, is it possible to place the import Javascript code in an event listener? E.g. only import and run the specific Javascript file on click of a button? I've tried it but unfortunately it logs an error for me, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @SergioKoh I am fairly sure that doing `import {} from "./foo.js"` is the same as doing `import "./foo.js"`.  `import "./foo.js"` just includes all exported members of `foo.js` into your current file.  Furthermore, you can actually import files on runtime using the `import` function.  You can read about that at [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/).  However, you don't need to pay attention to the notes on the `import` function being a draft, because it is actually supported by all modern browsers that support ES Modules.  I ran out of room; see next

Comment: > it is actually supported by all modern browsers that support ES Modules

Source: https://caniuse.com/es6-module-dynamic-import

Answer (score -1):

You could fairly easily just separate your javascript into separate files and include them all in your HTML as a `<script>`.